# Custom ArrayAdapter not populating ListView from within Fragment

Tags: android

So I have my main Activity called DINDUMENTARIA, which has a ViewPager and a custom Adapter to create a swipeable tablayout with two fragments. Now each of the Fragments should display a list of checkboxes which are generated from within a CustomAdapter and are different from one another.

Current state is:
[Fragment 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxorV.png) & [Fragment 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHbYy.png)

What I would want to achieve is having both Fragments have it's own independent list of checkboxes.

Main Problem is both fragments seem to be working on the same Activity and populate the same layout. I don't know, I'm confused.

Here goes the code:

'MainActivity'

```
public class DINDUMENTARIA extends CarrerasActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.planes);


    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    DINDUMENTARIA_Adapter adapter = new DINDUMENTARIA_Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);

    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
    myToolbar.showOverflowMenu();
    if(getSupportActionBar() != null){
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Diseño de Indumentaria");

}
}
```

FragmentPagerAdapter

```
public class DINDUMENTARIA_Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    private String tabTitles[] = new String[] {"Plan nuevo", "Plan viejo"};

    public DINDUMENTARIA_Adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return new DINDUMENTARIA_PN();
        } else {
            return new DINDUMENTARIA_PV();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];
    }
}
```

First Fragment code. Second Fragment should be the same but with different name and the HashMaps and Strings will be populated with different values.

```
public class DINDUMENTARIA_PN extends Fragment {

    public DINDUMENTARIA_PN() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();


        // LinkedHashMap de las materias de la carrera

        final LinkedHashMap<String, Materia> materias = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        final String[] nombresMaterias = {...};

        for (String nombreMateria : nombresMaterias) {
            materias.put(nombreMateria, new Materia(nombreMateria));
        }

        // Correlativas NIVEL 1

        materias.get("...").addCorrelativa(materias.get("..."));

        final ArrayList<Materia> listaMaterias = new ArrayList<>(materias.values());

        ((CarrerasActivity)getActivity()).reloadAll(listaMaterias);

        // El Adapter busca la materia en el HashMap y rellena el materias_list con la info del
        // HashMap y el formato de materias_list_item

        final MateriaAdapter adapter = new MateriaAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), listaMaterias);
        ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Asignar un click listener a cada materia creada

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View item, int position, long id) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) item;
                String nombre = (String) cb.getText();
                Materia materia = materias.get(nombre);
                if (materia.isEnabled()) {
                    materia.setAprobada(!materia.aprobada());
                    ((CarrerasActivity)getActivity()).storeMateria(materia.nombre(), materia.aprobada());
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                            "Para cursar " + materia.nombre() + " tenes que aprobar:\n" + materia.getStringCorrelativas(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                ((CarrerasActivity)getActivity()).reloadAll(listaMaterias);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.materias_list_notoolbar, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

CarrerasActivity, it's just a helper Activity for storing some reused functions across the app.

```
public class CarrerasActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.directory, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public void storeMateria(String idMateria, Boolean aprobada) {
        SharedPreferences pref = getMySharedPreferences();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(idMateria, aprobada);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public void reloadAll(ArrayList<Materia> materias) {
        SharedPreferences pref = getMySharedPreferences();

        for (Materia materia : materias) {
            String materiaId = materia.nombre();
            Boolean aprobada = pref.getBoolean(materiaId, false);
            materia.setAprobada(aprobada);
        }

        int aprobadas = 0;
        for (Materia materia : materias) {
            materia.refresh();
            boolean aprobada = materia.aprobada();
            storeMateria(materia.nombre(), aprobada);
            aprobadas += aprobada ? 1 : 0;
        }

        setAprobadas(aprobadas);
        setRestantes(materias.size() - aprobadas);
        setPorcentaje(Float.valueOf(aprobadas) / Float.valueOf(materias.size()));
    }

    private SharedPreferences getMySharedPreferences() {
        return getSharedPreferences(getLocalClassName(), MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    private void setAprobadas(int number) {
        TextView aprobadasTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aprobadas_text_view);
        aprobadasTextView.setText("Aprobadas: " + number);
    }

    private void setRestantes(int number) {
        TextView restantesTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.restantes_text_view);
        restantesTextView.setText("Restantes: " + number);
    }

    private void setPorcentaje(float number) {
        int porcentajeInt = (int) Math.round(number * 100);
        TextView porcentajeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.porcentaje_text_view);
        porcentajeTextView.setText(porcentajeInt + " %");
        ProgressBar laBarrita = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBarView);
        laBarrita.setProgress(porcentajeInt);
    }
}
```

Much appreciated